# Is smart group cache set to 0 OK for this situation?

Tags: smartgroups, acl

Using ACLs I have setup a group of users to have edit access to a smart group of contacts. The smart group is based upon the contact type. The problem is when one of these users creates a contact of this type, the contact is created OK but then an error message pops up to say they don't have access to the contact. They do have contact after a minute or so - the smart group cache is set to 1.  When I set the smart group cache to 0 then they have immediate access.  This client only has 12 smart groups. Smart group cache set to 0 solves the problem, but I'm not sure this is a good idea.  Are there any other solutions for this situation? - which can't be that uncommon.

Answer (score 2):

In your situation its reasonable to set cache time to 0 since your smart group is very less and hopefully those smart group criteria are not complexed.

Answer (score 2):

A different approach would be to replace the smart group by a static group and use CiviRules to add the new contacts into the group.

Comment: Aidan, thanks - I like that idea (should have thought of that!).